# Why (A - B) .^ 2 is not equal to (B - A) .^ 2 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a quantization function which quantize a 8bit gray scale image :

```
function mse = uni_quan(I, b)
   Q = I / 2 ^ (8 - b);
   Q = uint8(Q);
   Q = Q * 2 ^ (8 - b);
   mse = sum(sum((I - Q) .^ 2, 1), 2) / numel(I);
end
```

This function perform a uniform quantization on image `I` and convert it into a `b` bit image, then scale it in 0-255 range, Now I want to calculate [MSE (Mean Square Error)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) of this process

But the result for

```
mse = sum(sum((I - Q) .^ 2, 1), 2) / numel(I);
```

and

```
mse = sum(sum((Q - I) .^ 2, 1), 2) / numel(I);
```

is different. Can anyone please point me out whats the problem?
Thanks

Comment: I test it with sample code ,it seems to be ok Q = rand(4,3)
I= rand(4,3).*4
mse = sum(sum((Q - I) .^ 2, 1), 2) / numel(I)
mse = sum(sum((I - Q) .^ 2, 1), 2) / numel(I)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of maybe a 3-by-3 image?

Comment: In what way are the two results different?

Comment: can you show us the Q & I

Comment: @kkuilla I tested this function on the familiar `poat.tif` image and the result is quite different

Comment: @ABFORCE I meant the two `mse`. One theory could be that you get negative values somewhere and those values will be chopped of when you convert your image to a unit8 as unit8 will only hold positive values.

Comment: The `poat.tif` is a `291x240` 8bit image, on this image the results is different

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the type of the matrixes. You are combining two ***unsigned*** matrixes. So if `Q-I<0` then the result is 0 and it is different from I-Q.

In order to use `uint8`, you can compute  MSE in two steps:

```
%Compute the absolute difference, according to the sign
difference = Q-I;
neg_idx = find(I>Q);
difference(neg_idx) = I(neg_idx)-Q(neg_idx);

%Compute the MSE
mse = sum(sum((difference) .^ 2, 1), 2) / numel(I);
```

Comment: But the range of `int8` is -128 to +127 and my images may have value 255 for one of their pixels

Comment: @ABFORCE I added new code to compute the MSE using uint8. Hope it helps